# Error Serving Angular Build Output From Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I created an angular app in a folder called `angular-app` and successfully created a build using `ng build`. I tested the build using http-server. I navigated to the `angular-app` folder and ran 

`http-server ./dist`

And the angular app is rendered. Here is the `angular-app/dist/index.html` page of the build.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularApp</title>
  <base href="/angular-app/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Now inside the `angular-app` folder I created a `server.js` file to render the Angular build from a Node endpoint. Here is how the `angular-app/server.js` file looks:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('/angular', (req, res) => {
  console.log(__dirname);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Now on running the node server, I'm expecting the Node server to render the Angular app when loading `http://localhost:3000//angular`.
But instead I gives the following error in browser console.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/angular/angular-app/runtime.js 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
angular:13 GET http://localhost:3000/angular/angular-app/polyfills.js 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:3000/angular/angular-app/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

Any thoughts about what I'm missing ??

**Update :** As per comment changed app.get('/angular') to app.get('*') but still get the following error in console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
styles.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: try to change `<base href="/angular-app/">` to `<base href="/angular/angular-app/">`

Comment: tried but still the same error

Comment: your server not serve files like `http://localhost:3000/angular/angular-app/polyfills.js ` - you need to make redirection for all file requests to `dist/` - currently you make only one - /angular to /dist/index.html

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski tried as suggested but getting new errors in console. Updated the question with the new error. have a look

Comment: may be this will help: https://blog.cloudboost.io/run-your-angular-app-on-nodejs-c89f1e99ddd3

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski thnks it helped... but since I'm routing all request to the Angular app, i cant create any other routes .. rite ?

Comment: I think you can - just define other routes before `"*"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171232/discussion-between-ijade-and-kamil-kielczewski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server not serve files like `http://localhost:3000/angular/angular-app/polyfills.js` - you need to make redirection for all file requests to `dist/` - currently you make only one - `/angular` to `/dist/index.html`

Here you get more info about how to do it: https://blog.cloudboost.io/run-your-angular-app-on-nodejs-c89f1e99ddd3

Comment: is there a way to define a specific route to display the Angular app instead of * ?